# Jersey Client API throws exception for PUT Request JSONObject

Tags: json, api, rest, jersey, put

I'm getting following exception while trying to PUT JSONOBbject as like 
           inputData:
               {
             "key1":"value1",
             "key2":"value2"
                }

Code snippet:

```
          WebResource webResource = client
               .resource(url);
     response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
               .put(ClientResponse.class,inputData);
```

Exception:

```
        com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class org.json.JSONObject, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:533)
at httptransaction.CommonHttpClient.doPutConnect(CommonHttpClient.java:222)
```

Any pointers in resolution ?

Comment: You don't think you need the org.json library to serialize to JSON. Just pass in an normal POJO entity, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You need the jersey-json JAR in your classpath.

Comment: i do have jersey-json 1.16 added as maven dependency in my class path

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but with jersey-json 1.5.